# multilevel dropdown menu, problem with dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, drop-down-menu

The menu is here: http://voteacnng.org

Problem is with dropdown. It's a WordPress generated code.

Css:

```
.menu-tophorizontalmenu-container {
    margin: 18px auto 21px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1005px;
    display: block;
}

    .menu {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .menu * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

        .menu a {
            display: block;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 6px 16px;
            background: #000;
        }

        .menu li {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            font-size: 18px;
            margin: 2px 2px 0 0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

            .menu ul {
                position: absolute;
                top: 33px;
                left: 0;
                background: #000;
                display: none;
                list-style: none;
                z-index: 999px;
            }

                .menu ul li {
                    position: relative;
                    display: block;
                    width: 257px;
                    margin: 0 0 2px 0;
                    padding: 0;
                }

                    .menu ul li a {
                        display: block;
                        padding: 6px 16px;
                        color: #fff;
                        background: #000;
                    }

                    .menu ul li a:hover {
                        background: #1191B7;
                        color: #000;
                    }

                        .menu ul ul {
                            left: 257px;
                            top: 0;
                        }

                        .menu .menulink {

                        }

                        .menu .sub {
                            background: url(img/arrow-left.jpg) no-repeat 136px 8px;
                        }
```

It works if i remove the slideshow under the menu.

It has also a JavaScript:

```
function mainmenu(){$(" #menu-tophorizontalmenu ul ").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix $(" #menu-tophorizontalmenu li").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).show(400);
    },function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
    });} $(document).ready(function(){                  
mainmenu();});
```

Another problem is the arrow... The arrow needs to show up where a child menu is present.

Any ideas?

Comment: i think that is working just hover on meet your candidate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
visibility: "visible",display: "none"
```

This may be contradicting itself. Try just using `display:none;` when you want to hide and `display:block;` when you want to show.

It's hard to relate this to your code as the jQuery returns the following error:

> No elements were found with the
>   selector: "ul:first"

**Update (@11:07 GMT):**

I've used the following extra HTML and jQuery on this example - [check jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NtwGU/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-tophorizontalmenu-container">
  <ul id="menu-tophorizontalmenu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-home menu-item-36">
      <a href="http://voteacnng.org">Homepage</a>   
      <div style="display:none;">
        <p>I am a</p>
        <p>menu item</p>
        <p>can you see?</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    // Other menu items
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#menu-item-36").hover(function(){
    $("#menu-item-36").find("div").attr('style', 'display:block;');
    $(this).mouseout(function(){
        $("#menu-item-36").find("div").attr('style', 'display:none;');
    });
});
```

I've had to use a `<div />` and `<p />`s because there is something in your CSS thats not showing `<ul />`s You should try to use this as a start but sort out your HTML and CSS so you can mark it up correctly with `<ul>`s and `<li>`s.

Hope This helps.

Comment: thank you very much for the answers. i will definitely try your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to give me the answer. I made the changes you suggested but no success yet.

Comment: Hi @The Hun, check out my update on my answer. It's a starting point for you to go forward with.

Comment: Hi. I checked your solution and it works. I will need to change things in the WordPress core, the file which generates this menu structure. That I can do later. Until that, thanks a lot for your precious help.

Comment: Yes it works, however that nice jQuery effect is lost. Your help will be compensated with an accept.

Answer (score 1):

For arrow

```
$("#menu-tophorizontalmenu ul").closest('li').find('a').prepend('>>');
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to give me the answer. I added the code line but no success yet.

Comment: @The Hun isn't slide working, I think it is working just hover over `MEET YOUR CANDIDATE` menu sure, it drops down

Comment: No, the slide just working fine. No problem with that. The submenus are working only with the solution offered by @Alex Thomas in the above discussion. For that, if that will remain the only one solution, I will need to change things in the WordPress file which generates the menu structure. Until that I added your line, and the arrows now appears. See the link in my description. Thanks a lot. Another tricky thing is that a wrote myself the css, I just realised today that the "Twenty Ten" default WordPress theme support multilevel dropdown menus. How sad I am :)))

Comment: @The Hun, I think you should accept @Alex Thomas answer and ask another question regarding the change wordpress file. That would be the best. :) regards

Comment: Well I accepted his answer but I thank also for you. When I will have 15 reputation, I will get back here and will push the up arrow also for you. Now the menu works. I used `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'TopHorizontalMenu') ); ?> ` instead of the old `<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'TopHorizontalMenu' )); ?>`. Wow this code world... I just inspired from the "Twenty Ten" theme :)

Comment: Actually I was wrong. The menu worked just because the container class name suffered some changes. As I changed it in the CSS as it is generated in the page, the problem re-appeared. However, I added an answer below. If any solution will require and "accept" from me, I can post another issue, as I saw only one answer can be accepted at a question. Thanks.

Comment: @The Hun thank you. I am quite proficient with jquery but a complete haggard with wordpress. anyway I always vote up users who respond well.

Answer (score 1):

Current situation:

Arrows works thanks to @experimentX and we have solution for the dropdowns thanks to @Alex Thomas.

I figured out a thing. There is the following class:

```
.TopHorizontalMenu {
        margin: 18px auto 21px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 1005px;
        display: block;
    }
```

If i remove the `overflow`, will work the dropdowns but the slideshow will move to the top right side of the page. I think for this I need the alternative.